# Does "provable" include "proved by reduction to absrdity"?

Tags: logic, incompleteness

The incompleteness says that formal logic system (under certain condition) contains non provable TRUE sentence. It seems that "prove" means here "derive". Only TRUE sentence could be proved. If a sentence is FALSE, it cannot be proved, but the sentence of its inverse could be proved.

The reduction to absurdity can prove both TRUE and FALSE sentence. So does this mean that "provable" here doesn't include "proved by reduction to absurdity" ? Or in another words, the reduction to absurdity is not in the rules of inference of logic system ?

If "provable" doesn't include proved by the reduction to absurdity, could it be understood that "a non provable TRUE sentence" means that a sentence that is not provable but can be proved by reduction to absurdity that it's TRUE ?

Answer (score 2):

If you prove a **false** sentence, whether with reductio ad absurdum or any other rules, you will have an *inconsistent* system, and everything will be true in such a system.

In classical logic, and many other logics, reductio ad absurdum is a valid proof rule, and, assuming that your system is consistent, it can only be used to prove **true** sentences.

---

Reductio ad absurdum (RAA), in a formal system, is a rule of deduction of the following form.
$$\begin{array}{c} \neg S \\
\vdots \\
\bot \\ \hline
S\end{array}$$
The rule says that, if you from the negation of the sentence $S$ can derive a falsehood (which we denote by $\bot$), i.e. something that is always false (and which we informally call a contradiction), then you can conclude that your assumption that $\neg S$ is true must be **false**, so $S$ must be **true**.

Comment: For a sentence S, if the assumption of S is TRUE leads to contradiction, then S is FALSE. S is FALSE because it cannot be TRUE. It cannot be TRUE because if it were TRUE, contradiction will occur while the system is assumed no contradiction.

Comment: @user49413 Assume that $S$ is true and derive a contradiction. Then, by reductio ad absurdum, we can conclude that it is NOT the case that $S$ is true, hence the negation of $S$, $\neg S$, is true. Using reductio ad absurdum, you do not prove a sentence which is false, you prove that the *negation* of the sentence is true.

Comment: There are two senses of "proof" that should be distinguished: the proof of formal logic system which is in reality "derive", let's denote it "formal proof" here. As derive generates only TRUE sentence, so formal proof can prove only TRUE sentence. The second sense of proof is the proof everyone uses in his thinking, let's denote it "secular proof" here. The difference between formal proof and secular proof is the reduction to absurdity. formal proof doesn't contain reduction to absurdity. In fact, as formal proof proves only TRUE sentence, there is even no FALSE in a formal logic system.

Comment: Everything in a formal logic system is TRUE. So, there is no place for FALSE. Without FALSE, there is no contradiction. That's why formal proof doesn't include reduction to absurdity. In fact, a sentence S and its negation ¬S are two independent sentences in a formal logic system. If S is formally proved, the system doesn't know that ¬S could not be formally proved. If the system can prove that ¬S cannot be proved, it will prove its own consistency. We know now this is impossible.

Comment: But it's evident for secular proof that this ¬S is FALSE and the formal logic system cannot formally prove this ¬S (otherwise, it's in contradiction with the assumption of consistency). If we denote the logic system that uses secular proof a secular system, then all the real theories are secular system because all of them use reduction to absurdity. The question of completeness is: based on the same axioms, whether the formal system covers the secular system ? The incompleteness theorem says no. There exists a sentence that can be proved by secular proof but not by formal proof.

Comment: The incompleteness theorem shows that the reduction to absurdity is not only a proof gadget that makes proof easier. Reduction to absurdity is an essential proof method that can prove sentence that formal proof cannot prove. The incompleteness theorem shows also the importance of opposite: things is incomplete without opposite. Formal logic system ignores the FALSE, so it's incomplete.

Comment: @user49413 Your rambling comments make it seem like you are not really listening, so this is the last I will say, and then I will leave you to your devices: You say that "formal proof doesn't contain reduction to absurdity", which is just blatantly false. As I said, many logics, intuitionistic logic being the main exception, includes RAA as a deduction rule, so RAA is not a distinguishing factor between "secular" and formal proof. This renders all the rest of your question irrelevant.

Comment: If we agree that incompleteness means the existence of a TRUE sentence G that cannot be proved, and it's not an antinomy. So, TRUE and provable should mean different things. Otherwise, it becomes G is TRUE and not TRUE, or G is provable and not provable. It's an antinomy in both cases. One might say that G is TRUE but not being proved in the system. OK, in this case let's take the system I in which the incompleteness theorem is proved. There is a G' that is TRUE but not provable, then G' is proved TRUE in I and not provable in I. G' becomes an antinomy.

Comment: The "deduction machine" of a formal logic system (FLS) (as that of which the completeness talk about) generates new sentence based on the sentences existing in the system. It doesn't make contradiction check, that is, for each generated sentence S, it doesn't check whether ¬S exists already in the system. So, a FLS is unable to detect a contradiction. The detection of contradiction is also unnecessary because the machine of deduction doesn't make hypothetical deduction, that is, it doesn't generate sentence based on a assumed TRUE sentence. For these reasons there is no RAA in a FLS.

Answer (score 0):

The provable includes "proved by reduction to absurdity RAA".

It should be distinguished a logic system and a theory system. A theory system is based on a logic system by adding non logic axiom.

When a formal system contains enough rule of derivations, it can derive all TRUE formula (formula that is semantically TRUE). This is the completeness theorem.

What is surprising for the incompleteness theorem is that it shows that from a complete logic system, adding non logic axiom to make theory system, the completeness of the theory system changes when the theory system contains Peano arithmetic. The theory system will become incomplete.

So, the incompleteness is caused by the non logic axioms added, not due to the derivation rules it contains.